# How to monitor streaming apps Inside SCDF?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am novice to Spring Cloud Data flow and Stream Cloud Streaming Applications.
Currently my project diagram looks like following :

[image]

I route a POST request from outside client using zuul API gateway to a microservice called Composite. Composite creates a stream using REST POST and deployes onto Spring Cloud Data Flow Server. As far as I know the microservices mongodb and file run as co-existing JVM processes. If My client has to know the status of stream, status of the processed data, How should Composite Microservice interact with Spring Cloud Data Flow Server? Currently when I make POST call to deploy the stream I dont even get the status from SCDF Server. Does SCDF expose any hooks to look at the individual apps? Also how can I change the flow @runtime to create a dynamic mesh?

Currently I am using Local Spring Cloud Data Flow Server for development.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram! Could you also elaborate which runtime platform (_eg: cf, yarn, .._) are you using and the SCDF version?

Comment: Runtime platform is local @SabbyAnandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Runtime platform is local

`Local` runtime is recommended *only* for development purpose and if you're preparing for production, please make sure to choose a platform variant (*eg: cf, k8s, yarn, ..*) that comes with non-functional requirements to support reliable and durable execution of all the applications running in streaming pipeline.

> As far as I know the microservices mongodb and file run as co-existing JVM processes.

If your stream definition is `file | mongodb`, you'd have 2 different JVM's even when using `Local` runtime. They're independent Boot applications.

> How should Composite Microservice interact with Spring Cloud Data Flow Server?

Not clear what you mean by "composite" here. All the microservice applications in SCDF communicate via messaging middleware such as Kafka or Rabbit. SCDF provides the orchestration capability to run such applications into various runtime platforms.

> Currently when I make POST call to deploy the stream I dont even get the status from SCDF Server

You can use SCDF's REST-APIs to query for current status of the apps and it is platform agnostic. You can view the list of supported APIs by hitting the root URL (*see image below*) - there's a gap in docs - we will fix it. Following APIs could be useful for status checks.

[image]

> Does SCDF expose any hooks to look at the individual apps?

Once the apps are deployed in a runtime platform, you can take advantage of Boot's actuator endpoints to explore more details such as `trace`, `metrics`, `health`, `env` among others at each application level. See Boot's [actuator endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints) for more details. For instance, if your `mongodb` app is running locally and on port `23000`, then you can check granular metrics for this application at: `http://localhost:23000/metrics`.

[*As an FYI: future SCDF releases would include integrating Spring Boot + Spring Cloud Sleuth metrics and visual representation of the same.*]

> Also how can I change the flow @runtime to create a dynamic mesh?

If you're referring to editing a running streaming pipeline with addition/deletes, we are currently exploring design approach to support this functionality.